# Exception converting surrogate type created in ISerializable.GetObjectData when object is field in a Serializable class

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a value object class (UserData) that is marked as Serializable and contains another class (StringType) that is marked as Serializable and implements ISerializable so that it can return singleton instances.  The StringType class serializes and deserializes fine on it's own, but when it is used as a property on another object that is marked as Serializable, I get an exception truing to convert from the helper class deserialize into a singleton.

Object of type 'Spring2.Core.Test.Serialization.StringType_DEFAULT' cannot be converted to type 'Spring2.Core.Test.Serialization.StringType'.

I am using a BinaryFormatter and need to use that so that I can store this UserData object in an ASP.NET session using SQL server storage.

Here is a very stripped down version of the StringType class as well as some tests that show that serialization/deserialization work for StringType by itself, but not when as a field on UserData.

StringType:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Spring2.Core.Test.Serialization {

    public enum TypeState : short {
    DEFAULT,
    VALID,
    UNSET
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct StringType : ISerializable {
    private string myValue;
    private TypeState myState;

    public static readonly StringType DEFAULT = new StringType(TypeState.DEFAULT);
    public static readonly StringType UNSET = new StringType(TypeState.UNSET);

    private StringType(TypeState state) {
        myState = state;
        myValue = "";
    }

    public StringType(String s) {
        myValue = s;
        myState = TypeState.VALID;
    }

    public bool IsValid {
        get { return myState == TypeState.VALID; }
    }

    public bool IsDefault {
        get { return myState == TypeState.DEFAULT; }
    }

    public bool IsUnset {
        get { return myState == TypeState.UNSET; }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return IsValid ? this.myValue : myState.ToString();
    }


    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    StringType(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        myValue = (System.String)info.GetValue("myValue", typeof(System.String));
        myState = (TypeState)info.GetValue("myState", typeof(TypeState));
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        if (this.Equals(DEFAULT)) {
        info.SetType(typeof(StringType_DEFAULT));
        } else if (this.Equals(UNSET)) {
        info.SetType(typeof(StringType_UNSET));
        } else {
        info.SetType(typeof(StringType));
        info.AddValue("myValue", myValue);
        info.AddValue("myState", myState);
        }
    }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class StringType_DEFAULT : IObjectReference {
    public object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context) {
        return StringType.DEFAULT;
    }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class StringType_UNSET : IObjectReference {
    public object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context) {
        return StringType.UNSET;
    }
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
using System;

using NUnit.Framework;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Spring2.Core.Test.Serialization {

    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for BooleanType
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixture]
    public class DataTypeSerializationTest {


    [Test]
    public void ShouldBinarySerializeStringTypeWithValue() {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFmt = new BinaryFormatter();
        StringType s = new StringType("foo");

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("foo.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        binaryFmt.Serialize(fs, s);
        fs.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Original value: {0}", s.ToString());

        // Deserialize.
        fs = new FileStream("foo.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StringType s2 = (StringType)binaryFmt.Deserialize(fs);
        Console.WriteLine("New value: {0}", s2.ToString());
        fs.Close();

        Assert.AreEqual(s.ToString(), s2.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldBinarySerializeStringTypeUnset() {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFmt = new BinaryFormatter();
        StringType s = StringType.UNSET;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("foo.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        binaryFmt.Serialize(fs, s);
        fs.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Original value is UNSET: {0}", s.IsUnset);

        // Deserialize.
        fs = new FileStream("foo.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StringType s2 = (StringType)binaryFmt.Deserialize(fs);
        Console.WriteLine("new value is UNSET: {0}", s2.IsUnset);
        fs.Close();

        Assert.IsTrue(s2.IsUnset);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldDeserializeDataObject() {
        BinaryFormatter binaryFmt = new BinaryFormatter();
        UserData u = new UserData();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("foo.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        binaryFmt.Serialize(fs, u);
        fs.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Original value is UNSET: {0}", u.Name.IsUnset);

        // Deserialize.
        fs = new FileStream("foo.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        Object o = binaryFmt.Deserialize(fs);
        UserData u2 = (UserData)o;
        Console.WriteLine("new value is UNSET: {0}", u2.Name.IsUnset);
        fs.Close();
        Assert.IsTrue(Object.Equals(u, u2));
    }

    }


    [Serializable]
    public class UserData {
    private StringType name = StringType.DEFAULT;

    public StringType Name {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    }

}
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Cort

Comment: While you obviously have a reason for using a binary serializer, for testing purposes, do you get the same issue with XML serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cort you should change your IObjectReference implementations to return a struct.  The third unit test will fail, but it fails on the assertion of the Objects being equal, rather than throwing the type mismatch exception.

```
[Serializable]
public struct StringType_DEFAULT : IObjectReference {
public object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context) {
    return StringType.DEFAULT;
}
}

[Serializable]
public struct StringType_UNSET : IObjectReference {
public object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context) {
    return StringType.UNSET;
}
}
```

Comment: The values of the members of u and u2 are the same, so it's probably worth considering override Equals() to compare values.

Comment: Another curious thing is that the type mismatch exception is not thrown when running this under mono, but does when running under .net.  So probably a bug in the mono project as well :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It now seems obvious that my surrogate should be a struct just like what it is replacing is.  As for the tests, yes, my full featured object would have the Equals method implemented so that I could compare the object.  To make this test work, you could just compare the Name properties on each instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change StringType to be a class instead of a struct.

Comment: unfortunately, this example needed to stay as a struct for performance reasons -- it had actually started out as a class.  the real issue was the difference in declaring the type as a struct but the surrogate as a class -- making them both the same resolves the issue -- but making the surrogates a struct was the resolution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your DEFAULT and UNSET StringTypes are static readonly and constructed with the class, you shouldn't need to serialize them at all. Attribute them as [field:nonserialized].

Additionally, unless you have specific logic that needs to happen, you don't need to implement ISerializable for this class. Attributing it as [Serializable] should be enough.